# Reverse engineering controller sensitivity/aim for several games ie acceleration curves, deadzones, etc

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

A machine learning project I am working on requires me to interface with an Xbox controller connected to a PC. The implementation must do the following two things:

Record the joystick input from the controller into a file at regular intervals, along with an associated screenshot from a game. (ex: 60 times a second).

With this data I want to try to replicate/reverse engineer a few different FPS games sensitivity’s,dead zones, acceleration curves.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I'd go about doing this? I'm not sure where to start. If this question isn't appropriate for this sub, I’m where could I ask?